# Analyze multiple dataframe columns to create a new categorical variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to write a program to analyze a dataframe by taking a subset of rows and checking their columns to determine a categorical value.

All the data is in a dataframe.  'var1' and 'var2' from each 'batch' need to be characterized:

```
if var1 == 'white' and var2 == 'one' then 'L1'
if var1 == 'white' and var2 == 'two' then 'L2'
if var1 == 'blue' and var2 == 'one' then 'L3'
if var1 == 'blue' and var2 == 'two' then 'L4'
```

The new 'categorical' variable ('L1', L2', 'L3', 'L4') are combined in an array with the first date from the 'batch'. Eventually all the arrays are gathered into a new dataframe. I think combining into a new array is optional. The new categorical value could be a new dataframe column and I get the date in a second step.

I wound up writing a complex loop to perform the analysis. It works, but I am wondering if there is a more 'python' way to perform this same task.

Here is working sample code that accomplishes my task:

````
import pandas as pd
import datetime

col = ['fruit', 'batch', 'dtm', 'var1','var2']

data = [
        ['apple', 1, datetime.datetime(2020,1,1,0,0,0), 'white', 'two'],
        ['apple', 1, datetime.datetime(2020,2,1,0,0,0), 'blue', 'one'],
        ['apple', 1, datetime.datetime(2020,2,1,0,0,0), 'blue', 'one'],
        ['apple', 2, datetime.datetime(2020,2,1,0,0,0), 'blue', 'two'],
        ['apple', 2, datetime.datetime(2020,3,1,0,0,0), 'blue', 'one'],
        ['orange',3, datetime.datetime(2020,1,1,0,0,0), 'white', 'one'],
        ['orange',3, datetime.datetime(2020,3,1,0,0,0), 'white', 'two'],
    ['apple', 4, datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0), 'blue', 'one'],
    ['apple', 4, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0), 'blue', 'one'],
    ['orange', 5, datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 'white', 'two'],
    ['orange', 5, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0), 'white', 'two'],
    ['orange', 6, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0), 'white', 'two'],
    ['orange', 6, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0), 'white', 'two'],
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = col)

df.set_index(['fruit', 'batch'], inplace = True)

header_list = ['categorical', 'first_dtm']
data_list = []

data_list = []

for fruit, new_df in df.groupby(level=1):
    if new_df['var1'].str.contains('white').sum() > 0:
        if new_df['var2'].str.contains('one').sum() > 0:
            data_list.append(['L1',new_df['dtm'][0]])
        else:
            data_list.append(['L2', new_df['dtm'][0]])
    else:
        if new_df['var2'].str.contains('one').sum() > 0:
            data_list.append(['L3', new_df['dtm'][0]])
        else:
            data_list.append(['L4', new_df['dtm'][0]])

df_out = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns=header_list)```
````

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve with words than with code for others to understand quickly.

Comment: Appreciate your looking. I added some text to hopefully clarify the question. Thanks!

Comment: "with the first date from the 'batch'" is really the first index (`[0]`) or the oldest date?

Comment: In my dataset it is the same, but oldest date is what I want.